# Why would the character 'A' be compared with 0x41?

Tags: c++, string

I was looking at some C++ code and found the following construct:

```
if('A' == 0x41) {
  // ...
} else if('A' == 0xc1) {
  // ...
} else {
  // ...
}
```

I get a [Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) warning saying:

> Warning    C4127 conditional expression is constant.

Visual Studio is clearly right - surely 'A' is defined to be 0x41. Why is the author writing this code, given that two out of the three branches are dead code?

Comment: They're not necessarily dead code, perhaps it's just a daft way to check the character set.

Comment: 'A' = C1 in EBCDIC

Comment: @George That's a good guess. A check for usage of ASCII char input or other.

Comment: While it's pretty good chance that the author is doing a character encoding check, it's hard to say anything for *certain* without more context. Like what is happening in the code you don't show?

Comment: I would put it in a utility header as `#define IS_CHSET_EBCDIC ('A' == 0xc1)`etc.; or, in modern C++, make it a `constexpr`.

Comment: I've used a platform where 'A' == 0xC1.  All three branches are live *on the right machine*.

Comment: @MartinBonner "All three branches are live on the right machine": Certainly not, or am I missing something? You mean "either one of the three..."

Comment: Does that even work? I.e. would compilers convert / modify the source file according to the current plattform? From my understanding the branch depends on the charset of the plattform where the source file is edited, not the plattform where code is executed. If that's not true, how does it work?

Comment: @b.buchhold I see where you're coming from and i'm not sure why the checks aren't macros but i'd imagine that's the idea, you can use the same code to compile for multiple and perhaps many different platforms.

Comment: @harold true, but then the code essentially checks for the charset of the source file and not for any form of input

Comment: @b.buchhold - No, you can cross compile from a PC to the mainframe. So 'A' must mean the value of the character in the execution character set.

Comment: It seems like this might best be done using preprocessor conditional inclusion (e.g. #if 'a' == 41 ... #else ... #endif) to do this rather than dynamic branches so that you don't get warnings like these. Would that work?

Comment: @templatetypedef The character encoding at preprocessing time is allowed to be different from the character encoding at compile time. See [cpp.cond]p4: "Whether the numeric value for these character literals matches the value obtained when an identical character literal occurs in an expression (other than within a #if or #elif directive) is implementation-defined."

Comment: These young whippersnappers who are so accustomed to the ASCII character set have no idea of all the fun they are missing.

Comment: Regarding the meaning of character expressions you might find the discussion of the current compiler knowing what `\n` means because the compiler that created it knew it interesting - https://www.ece.cmu.edu/~ganger/712.fall02/papers/p761-thompson.pdf

Comment: 'A' is a compilation constant. So, assuming the compiler is told the correct source file character set encoding, all this does is let the program know what the compiler was told to use as the execution character set encoding.

Comment: Seeing new things every day in Stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

`0xc1` is the `EBCDIC` character set code for `A`. The author is testing for such a machine.

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGH4D_15.1.3/com.ibm.xlf1513.aix.doc/language_ref/asciit.html

Comment: And on the very late, not very lamented Prime, 'A' would have been 0xC1!

Comment: Isn't there a better way to check what charset the compiler uses for the target machine?

Comment: @Bergi almost certainly. This is an example of using code to find code - a universally accepted (in mature c++ circles) evil.

Comment: @RichardHodges: I've yet to see one that works in all cases.

Comment: How odd... is there a better way than this to check the character set? How common is this alternate character set!

Comment: "is there a better way than this to check the character set?" There is no standard way to do so. In C11, there is a way to check if certain Unicode encodings are being used, but MSVC will not even fully support C99 (which predates C11). "How common is this alternate character set!" Besides IBM mainframes? Not at all.

Comment: @Joshua All cases in theory or all cases in practice? The former is not useful in practice, the latter is more than covered by the check in the question.

Comment: So what's the final `else` branch for?  Is there a still-in-use character encoding that's compatible with neither ASCII nor EBCDIC?

Comment: @dan04 None that I know of, but it could realistically be as simple as a "unknown encoding, print error message" branch.

Comment: 'A' is also 0xC1 in Apple II DOS 3.3 character encoding, which is ASCII OR'd with 0x80.

Comment: @Rhymoid There is actually a good chance that Microsoft will implement C11 before ever supporting C99. They were one of the vendors that pushed back against difficult to implement C99 features, two of which are no longer mandatory in C11 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)#Optional_features.

Comment: EBCDIC encoding is still used in the main seismic geophysics data format. But of course the machines don't use those encodings.

Comment: If you want a binary that will run on either / any charset encoding, then it's not just a compile-time issue.

Comment: @Rhymoid I thought it's kind of obvious, but... MSVC++ is a C++ compiler, not a C compiler. The C compiler is only included for backwards compatibility. Are you expecting MSVC++ to also support Objective-C, just because it has "C" in the name? It's not like there's a small amount of alternatives if you really want to use C on Windows :)

Comment: @dan04 Maybe there's some weird compiler that uses char literals that are wide chars? Or perhaps some multi-byte character set? This is really the kind of thing that should be documented in code (or a specification) :D

Comment: @Luaan It is pointless to suggest that I think MSVC supports Objective C. The currect alternatives are either pricey or not ABI-compatible.

Comment: @Rhymoid Well, the x86 CPU can also execute random image data, if it just so happens to consist of x86 instructions that are valid enough :) You're focusing on the implementation detail instead of on the contract - and the contract is "backwards compatibility support for C89" (and lately "with some features from C99/C11 since they mesh well with the C++ additions or there were enough people who cared"). It's not easy to find outright statement of that nowadays, since most of the product overviews are done in that new hip style that focuses on popular features, but that's how it is.

Comment: @Rhymoid So you're basically saying that MSVC is bad because it doesn't support C, and the alternatives that support C don't actually work or are too expensive? There used to be a time where C was a feature subset of C++, but that hasn't been true for quite a while now. Obviously, back in those days, a conformant C++ compiler had to be able to compile conformant C code; but today? There really isn't much of a reason to expect that, other than history (and that's why there's the backwards compatible old-C in MSVC++).

Comment: @Luaan The C++ standard requires compatibility with a conforming C implementation (it's part of the requirements for `extern "C"` declarations). If MSVC by design doesn't conform to the C standard in any of its modes, which conforming C implementation is MSVC designed to be compatible with? Is it documented anywhere? Or does MSVC simply not support this part of the C++ standard? (It would make sense: exact `extern "C"` support as required by the standard is missing in multiple compilers, for various reasons.)

Comment: @Luaan I very much disagree with the notion that an ABI-compatible C compiler isn't needed. There is still quite a bit of vital software that is written in C, ranging from essentials libraries (e.g. zlib, SDL2) to compilers, runtimes, and runtime extensions for various programming languages (e.g. Python). Like it or not, C is more of a lingua franca than C++.

Comment: @Rhymoid Well, of course MSVC++ supports C linking; all of Windows API is C-style declarations and functions, and it's the most common way to interop (along with COM). It would be a lot harder to make all those non-C++ platforms conform with the API if that weren't true, and that would hardly allow Windows to be as popular as it is :)

Comment: @hvd I couldn't find it documented in enough detail anywhere. All I could find is just the generic "MSVC++ supports C and (MS)C++ linkage". The last time I checked, there was full support for C89 (again, this was designed only to easy the codebase transfer from C to C++ - it's just that the transfer wasn't as popular as expected, I guess), and supposedly, VS2013 added support for C99. There's also implicit support for all the parts where the C and C++ standards are conforming to each other. You still use the C++ compiler for the linkage, though, not a C compiler. I'm not saying it's great :)

Comment: @Luaan When I wrote ABI, I meant ABI. The GNU toolchain does not support Microsoft's x86-64 ABI. Clang appears to support it, which is probably the only valid counterargument to my point, but Clang' Windows support is also quite young.

Comment: @Rhymoid Ah, okay. Sure, that would be nice. There used to be tons of C compilers for Windows, but it seems that pretty much none of those ever supported C99 or higher, and they haven't been developed in quite a while. C just isn't used much in the Windows world, which in turn means that you get poor tooling for C, which of course makes it even less likely you're going to pick C as your language of choice. Out of reasonably current compilers, I think only Intel's and Clang are really useful (I know that MS used the Intel compiler in the past, maybe they still do instead of making their own).

Comment: @Rhymoid And Pelles C seems to be still under active development - overall, it seems like the best choice if you want a free C compiler that's reasonably current. No idea how it compares in e.g. performance to the competition, though.

Comment: @Luaan To my knowledge, MSVC 2013 added most of the missing C99 library support, but still lacked some of the C99 language features (and by extension, library support that requires those features, such as `tgmath.h`), and MSVC 2015 improved on that a bit.  Amusingly, though, some parts of the C library also seem to have better support than their required features (such as `complex.h`, which uses a non-conforming implementation of complex numbers, whereas the official `T _Complex` doesn't seem to be supported).  It's getting there, only about a decade and a half late.

Answer (score 11):

At first sight might look like that is dead code but 'A' == 0x41 not always will return true..

what the developer tried to do here is *lazily* find what encoding is the machine implementing **ASCII** or any variant of **EBCDIC**

as @Richard suggested Capital **a** is mapped to **0xc1** in the [International - Extended Binary Coded Decimal Interchange Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)  see table below in the 2 branch of the if else...

[image]

another different value could be found by ASCII for exmaple:

[image]

he could as well have done:

```
if('p' == 0x70) {
  // ...
} else if('p' == 0x97) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: In the second paragraph - did you mean EBCDIC instead of EBDIC?